# Как из функции получить доступ к внешнему массиву?

Tags: php

Как из функции получить доступ к внешнему массиву?

```
$array = array('Hello World');

function test() {
    return $array[0]; // здесь ошибка
}

echo test();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как вариант передать массив `$array` в качестве аргумента метода

```
$array = array('Hello World');

function test($arr) {
    return $arr[0];
}

echo test($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно внутри функции объявить, что просишь доступ к глобальной переменной.

```
function test() {
    global $array;
    return $array[0];
}
```

Альтернативный вариант - использовать [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.globals.php):

```
function test() {
    return $GLOBALS["array"][0];
}
```

Comment: Необходимо помнить, что это может быть полезно только в качестве ознакомительных целей (хотя польза от этого сомнительная). В реальной жизни так делать не стоит

Comment: @BOPOH Иногда глобальные переменные полезны как таковые, по ссылке есть хороший вариант со статическими методами `glb::get("varname")`, `glb::set("varname", value)`.

Comment: @BOPOH Почему по вашему использовать global не желательно?

Comment: @Vesper, вы считаете комментарий с 27 минусами "хорошим вариантом"? `global` плох тем, что вы не контролируете используемое значение. Кроме вас это значение может быть изменено каким-либо другим куском кода (который находится за пределами вашей функции) и в результате там может оказаться далеко не то, что будет нужно вам. Подробности можно почитать [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087)

Comment: @BOPOH Если нужны именно глобальные переменные, то да, этот вариант хорош для унификации кода обращения к глобальным переменным. Ибо всего одно место, куда можно всобачить отладочный код, чтобы гарантировать, что именно тут происходит изменение глобальной переменной. А на всё остальное натравить `grep $GLOBALS` и `"^\s*global "` после чего заменить либо вызвать `git blame` с оргвыводами.

Comment: Алсо, loose coupling ради него самого - зло. Также я считаю, что Карфаген должен быть разрушен.