# В связи взломом FL.ru

Tags: php

Привет!
Взломали тут сайт fl.ru
Уверен, что все знают :)
Движок сайта выложили в открытый доступ.
И вот читаю я коменты на хабре :)
И наткнулся на это:

```
"Глобальные переменные в проекте на PHP в 2015-м году.
Говорите что хотите, но эти люди заслужили подобный исход."
```

И это:

```
"Мне кажется, что если код сильно завязан на глобальных переменных, его надо выкинуть, и переписать проект заново.
Тащить за собой это проклятье четвёрки — самоубиство, маразм и гимн лени в одной куче."
```

Я ведь правильно понимаю, что речь идет про $GLOBALS?
Кто нибудь может привести пример такого говнокода? :)

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/263703/

Comment: [Пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437240/5079) или вас исходники где-нить на гитхабе интересуют?

Comment: @BOPOH Какое ТЗ, такое решение :D

Comment: @Vesper, ничего личного, я просто привел пример использования `globals` )) Если бы я отвечал, по ссылке мог быть и мой ответ )

Comment: @Vesper, спасибо! :) Т.е. global name уже не актуально? :) А как на счет $GLOBALS? Тоже говнокод? :))

Comment: @BOPOH там в комметах пишут, мол 2015 год. глобальные переменные не актуальны :) И приравнивают их к говнокоду :) Я использую несколько переменных $GLOBALS

Т.е. я говнокодер? xD

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/4041128 - это еще в 11 году еще писали, а на дворе уже 16 практически